# trap fails to catch SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, bash, segmentation-fault, bash-trap

I'm using this script to test trap:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "echo segfault!" SIGSEGV
g++ forever.cpp
./a.out
```

And `forever.cpp` just runs a recursive function:

```
void forever(){
    forever();
}
int main(){
    forever();
}
```

However it gives `Segmentation fault: 11` instead of printing `segfault`. I'm not sure why.

Comment: caused by stack overflow caused by infinite recursion

Comment: Yes. But isn't `trap` supposed to catch the segmentation fault signal?

Comment: @XiangxinSun: Yes, but only in `bash` itself, not any programs it launches.

Comment: You can see my answer below- what you want to trap is SIGCHLD, using `trap ... CHLD`, and then check `$?` there. This will have the side-effect of trapping every time an external process returns, but as long as you check for the code you're looking for, it won't be a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `trap` statement traps signals received by `bash`, not its children. The child receives the segfault and will be exiting with an appropriate exit code. You should therefore check the exit code from the child process. As you can see from [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html), the exit code is 128+signal number. `SEGV` is 11 (see `man signal`), so you will get an exit code of 139. So simply test `$?` against 139, and you have done.

Comment: Thanks! `trap 'if [[ $? -eq 139 ]]; then echo "segfault"; fi' EXIT` does the job.

Answer (score 4):

The bash trap will catch a segfault in bash itself, not in a process spawned from bash.

In this case you are spawning a process, and that process gets a segfault. You would need to install a signal handler in the C-program forever.cpp to catch that.

Comment: I see. Is there a way that doesn't require modifying `forever.cpp`?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to trap when bash catches the SIGCHLD from the process it forked- you can use `trap <expression> CHLD` for this

`trap 'if [[ $? -eq 139 ]]; then echo "SIGSEGV IN CHILD PROCESS, EXITING"; exit 139; fi' CHLD`

Or, if you want a general purpose trap handler, you could do something like:

```
process_returned() {
  local exit_code=$?  # Save the exit code for the rest of the function
  [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]] && return
  if [[ $? -eq 139 ]]; then
    echo "SIGSEGV IN CHILD PROCESS, EXITING";
    exit 139
  fi
  echo "Something other than SIGSEGV was returned ($exit_code)";
  ... trap handling logic ...
}

trap process_returned CHLD
```

Just keep in mind that `process_returned` will fire *every time* a process you invoke returns- the first logic in the handler function (if you use a function) should probably be `[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && return`

The reason you may want to use a function is because if you're interested in `SIGSEGV`, you're *probably* also interested in `SIGBUS`, `SIGILL` and `SIGABRT` as these can all occur as a result of memory corruption in a process

- `SIGSEGV` is caused specifically by either an attempt to access and unmapped virtual memory address in a process *or* by an attempt to *execute* on a memory page that is mapped but without executable permissions
- `SIGBUS` tends to occur either as a result of hardware faults or in the case of some RISC architecture CPUs, as a result of an unaligned read or write. This happens on, for example, SPARC, PA-RISC, MIPS and I'm sure one or two others- though not ARM, x86 or x86_64- at least not with any of the standard store/load instructions. It's possible there are alignment requirements with some of the extensions on modern x86 / x86_64 chips.
- `SIGILL` is raised when the CPU can't decode the instruction at the currently executing address. The most common cause for this is the program counter got corrupted while it was saved on the stack and returned to some address within a multi-byte CPU instruction
- `SIGABRT` is raised internally by glibc `malloc()` when it detects
  inconsistencies in heap metadata due to heap corruption. Of all of
  these, `SIGABRT` is the one that you can't always assume has anything
  to do with memory corruption or a fault related to memory, so you may
  not want to catch that one